# find a div without knowing full id

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension associated with a website. I want to change the text in a div but the div has a dynamic id and has no other ways for me to identify it (i.e. no class)

the div looks like this

```
<div id="button select-leg routing_idens-640bbf2f16,"> text... </div>
```

the div always has "button select-leg routing_idens-" in the id

could I use something similar to .find() that will find divs with the string that always occurs?

Comment: The id looks like list of classes. Strange having id with spaces inside.

Comment: Agreed. This is almost certainly wrong. `button` should almost certainly be a class, as you're likely to have more than one. Otherwise it's very poor naming for an `id`. Really, you ought to have a class `routing_idens` and an ID `routing_idens-640bbf2f16`.

Answer (score 2):

If you make your ID valid:

```
<div id="button_select-leg_routing_idens-640bbf2f16,"> text... </div>
```

You can use the the [`attribute-starts-with-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) :

```
$('div[id^="button_select-leg_routing_idens-"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery:

```
$('div[id^="button select-leg routing_idens-"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to get by tag name (div) or use querySelectorAll('div') and then cycle through those returned elements checking their ID against a substring.

Heres an example. You will also have to correct your ID, with spaces it is invalid.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for(var e in elements) {
    if(elements[e].id.indexOf('some_substring') !== -1) {
        // Now elements[e] contains the element you want.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the modern JavaScript libraries (JQuery, Mootools, Dojo etc.) provide very efficient ways (selectors) to find certain elements on a page. 
   You can iterate through the  elements and select the 7th (if that is constant) or check if it's id starts with "button select-leg routing_idens-".

Jquery: [jquery.com](http://jquery.com)

Mootools: [mootools.net](http://mootools.net)